# converting Japanese characters to hex not working

Tags: java, apache-commons

My code is very simple (using commons-codec-1.10.jar)

```
System.out.println(Hex.encodeHex("三菱グループ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true));
```

it yields e4b889e88fb1e382b0e383abe383bce38397 in my PC, but in accoridng to http://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter, it should be 4e0983f130b030eb30fc30d7. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you sure the site you posted is doing it correctly and is using the same encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hex.encodeHex` is working fine, but the results are the UTF-8 encoding, whereas [codebeautify.org](http://codebeautify.org/) appears to be using UTF-16.

Let's take 三 to start with. That's U+4E09. In UTF-16 that's encoded as 4E 09, which matches the start of your codebeautify output. In UTF-8 it's encoded as E4 B8 89, which matches your Java output.

If you want UTF-16, just use `StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE` instead of `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. (But only do it if you *really* want UTF-16. UTF-8 is a better encoding to use in most cases, IMO.)